# MS WORD - Remove Field Code , Retain Value in Header

Tags: vba

I have this Word VBA code, which removes field codes, but retains their values. This works well, but not in the header. How can I edit it to work for the body of document ( and header/footer as well ) ?

```
Sub RemoveFieldCodeButRetainValue()
    Dim d As Document
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    Dim strTemp As String

    Set d = ActiveDocument

    For iTemp = d.Fields.Count To 1 Step -1

        strTemp = d.Fields(iTemp).Result

        d.Fields(iTemp).Select

        With Selection
            .Fields(1).Delete
            .TypeText strTemp
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I realize this isn't exactly the answer to the question, but using:

```
For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
    fld.Unlink
Next
```

will preserve the value while deleting the underlying field. As far as I know, you could use the same technique while looping through the various story ranges as suggested in the other answer for the header/footer areas.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it:

Use two macros:

```
Sub CtrlAPlusFNine()
    Selection.WholeStory
    Dim oStory As Range
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                oStory.Fields.Update
            Wend
        End If
    Next oStory
lbl_Exit:
    Set oStory = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub


Sub RemoveFieldCodeButRetainValue()
    Dim d As Document
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    Dim strTemp As String
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    For iTemp = d.Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
        strTemp = d.Fields(iTemp).Result
        d.Fields(iTemp).Select
        With Selection
            .Fields(1).Delete
            .TypeText strTemp
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

..and call these two from a third macro using  Application.Run

Comment: but i have another query on the same: how do I delete a 'cross reference' (through a vba macro) but retain its value  ?